# Battery not fully charged (it shows 100%)

Tags: power-management, battery, tlp

Ever since I upgraded from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 I've been noticing that the battery does not last as much as it used to. The bar indicator shows that it is fully charged but I ran tlp-stat and I got this:

```
+++ Battery Status
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/manufacturer                   = MSI
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/model_name                     = BTY-M6D
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_full_design             =   7800 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_full                    =   2466 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_now                     =   2387 [mAh]
```

So it means that the battery is not fully charged even though it says 96%. It also says charged rather than keep charging it until it reaches 100%.

Is there any way to solve this issue? Or it might be really a hardware issue with the battery rather than a software issue with the upgrade?

Thank you.

Comment: When it comes to hardware, it's best to replace it. Software solutions only go so far

Comment: There is definitely something about ubuntu 14.04 because this issue started once I upgraded from 12.04. I've been noticing that the battery LED switches from orange to blue and according to msi (msi GT70) that LED is blue when the system is in sleep mode. This happened while I was using the computer, it was not sleeping for sure. On the other side, I switches to windows and let it drain to 0%, after charging it (which took a long time), that charge_full increased a little bit. I'll try repeating the process to see if I can increase it further. For this  reasons I believe it's something else

Comment: OK, try a different kernel. When you boot, get to the OS selection menu (aka grub ) and chose Advanced Options, then chose any option with older kernel and one that is not saying "(recovery mode )". You can check what is your current kernel with `uname -r` command. Otherwise, I don't have any other suggestions

Comment: I've just did that and at this moment the battery is charging (slower than before...which I hope it's a good sign) but as it is charging the battery LED instead of being orange is blinking blue again......It's definitely something about ubuntu 14.04

Comment: 5 minutes later the battery LED is back to orange and the battery is charging now. It seems that during the time it's blinking blue the battery does not charge. Then it switches and starts charging again. Could that have 'ruined' the battery? How can I avoid this to happen?

Comment: So did it charge fully with the older kernel ?

Comment: Not yet. I've been using windows to charge charge it to 100%, leaving it plugged for a few hours and then unplugged until it gets to 2% so it hibernates (configured). Then leaving it off for some hours (overnight) and then charging it to 100% with a few hours plugged afterwards. By doing this twice so far charge_full went up to 2602 so far. I believe the battery is highly uncalibrated (I hope) rather than worn out. Any thoughts about this?

Comment: Last night I did the same steps but with ubuntu (charging to 100%, leaving it plugged for a few hours and then letting it drain and hibernate and charging to 100%) and full_charge dropped to 2495. If I had done the same on windows that value would have increased. There is definitely something with ubuntu's power management that f'ed up my battery.

Answer (score 0):

Your battery is worn out to 30% capacity. Solution: replace the battery.